# Save Kinect's color camera video stream in to .avi video

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I want to save the video streams that is captured by Kinect's Color camera to .avi format video, I tried many ways of doing this but nothing was succeeded. Has anyone successfully done this? I'm using Kinect for Windows SDK and WFP for application development

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest workaround would be to use a screen capture software like http://camstudio.org/.

There is also post with the same question her:
[Kinect recording a video in C# WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039027/kinect-recording-a-video-in-c-sharp-wpf)

As far as I understand you need to to save the single frames delivered by the kinect by into a  video file. This post should explain how to do it [How to render video from raw frames in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232550/how-to-render-video-from-raw-frames-in-wpf).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AVIFile Windows API using interop:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756808(v=vs.85).aspx

or you can use a wrapper like this one, done by Corina John
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library