# How to save kinect color video as stream on hard disk by Kinect SDK 2 in WPF

Tags: wpf, video, stream, kinect

I have a question about save kinect color video as stream
How to save Kinect's color video as stream to hard by Kinect SDK 2 in WPF???

i read this link: [Save Kinect's color camera video stream in to .avi video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334560/save-kinects-color-camera-video-stream-in-to-avi-video)

Comment: we can use VideoWriter classs and WriteFrame function in emgucv to save video as avi file, but this function not streaming,

Comment: i want to develop program that can save continuously kinect color data source to file on hard not RAM, because memory not enough

Answer (score 4):

For a project, I had to do this. What I've done may not fulfill all your requirements but it may give you an idea. At first I saved every color frame image in local drive with a sequencial naming. Then with ffmpeg I converted those sequential image to video file, in my case it was mp4 video, not avi.

To save color image frame sequentially, you may code like below,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Kinect;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Kinect_Video_Recorder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        KinectSensor ks;
        ColorFrameReader cfr;
        byte[] colorData;
        ColorImageFormat format;
        WriteableBitmap wbmp;
        BitmapSource bmpSource;
        int imageSerial;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ks = KinectSensor.GetDefault();
            ks.Open();
            var fd = ks.ColorFrameSource.CreateFrameDescription(ColorImageFormat.Bgra);
            uint frameSize = fd.BytesPerPixel * fd.LengthInPixels;
            colorData = new byte[frameSize];
            format = ColorImageFormat.Bgra;
            imageSerial = 0;

            cfr = ks.ColorFrameSource.OpenReader();
            cfr.FrameArrived += cfr_FrameArrived;
        }

        void cfr_FrameArrived(object sender, ColorFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.FrameReference == null) return;

            using (ColorFrame cf = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
            {
                if(cf == null) return;
                cf.CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray( colorData, format);
                var fd = cf.FrameDescription;

                // Creating BitmapSource
                var bytesPerPixel = (PixelFormats.Bgr32.BitsPerPixel) / 8;
                var stride = bytesPerPixel * cf.FrameDescription.Width;

                bmpSource = BitmapSource.Create(fd.Width, fd.Height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, stride);

                // WritableBitmap to show on UI
                wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmpSource);
                kinectImage.Source = wbmp;

                // JpegBitmapEncoder to save BitmapSource to file
                // imageSerial is the serial of the sequential image
                JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpSource));
                using (var fs = new FileStream("./img/" + (imageSerial++) + ".jpeg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    encoder.Save(fs);
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above example saves the images in jpeg format. if you need to save it as png format use [`PngBitmapEncoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Now we have saved sequential images in hard drive. To convert these sequential images to video file you can use [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images). You can also use [Aforge.net](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/ffmpeg.html). But I've never used it. In my case I called the `ffmpeg.exe` process from my C# program like below.

`Process.Start("ffmpeg.exe", "-framerate 10 -i ./img/%d.jpeg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p kinect_video.mp4");`

Note:

1. Make your Build target x64. This will increase the memory limit of the program.
2. I've coded a basic [implementation](https://github.com/rafaftahsin/Kinect-v2-Color-Frame-Recorder) regarding this. You can check out if you want.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i used your idea dear Rafaf Tahsin, your code is slowly because this code:   `wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmpSource);` if you delete this code and use the `kinectImage.Source = bmpSource;` instead of that, it's good

Comment: there's a big problem and this is voice, i change my question: how to record and save voice and color video as stream that they are match together?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to save both audio and video synchronously from Kinect v2. I'd like to suggest you to make a new question regarding this, hope someone will help. Thanks