# How to Get Audio Stream from Kinect v2 AudioSource

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, voice

I'm developing a program to record Color and Audio data source of Kinect V2.0 as video in WPF.
 record Color data source is done such that explained in: [How to save kinect color video as stream on hard disk by Kinect SDK 2 in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010067/how-to-save-kinect-color-video-as-stream-on-hard-disk-by-kinect-sdk-2-in-wpf) ;and now, my question is: how to record kinect Audio data source as stream on hard disk in wav or mp3 or other format?

Comment: I have an idea that get them of AudioBasics-WPF Kinect v2 sample code: we can save each audio frame as a single wav file: subFrame.CopyFrameDataToArray(this.audioBuffer); and then collect them to a single wav file

Comment: question is: how to save a byte array as wav file