# Kinect 2 shows black screen while capturing Infrared Basics

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, infrared

I am trying to use Kinect 2 and SDK v2 for capturing Infrared Images/videos. 
Kinect shows Depth and RGB images properly, But when i try to visualize Infrared Basics in Kinect for Window. It does not show any image, rather a black screen. 
What is the reason for it. I reinstalled SDK v2, but still the same problem. In a similar post some one suggested that reinstall a newer version, which I did. But still the same problem. Can any one suggest any solution?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by updating GPU Driver. It has a conflict/bug/error with older version. However Nvidia removed it. And if one install new driver, it start showing infrared images.
Attention for your graphics card setting, Maybe changing your computer to auto or Inter HD Graphics will work.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use "KinectConfigurationVerifierSetup" for test system requirements. and i suggest you that use Infrared Basic-WPF Samples in SDK Browser, also you could use that sample code and install them to your computer. if still infrared data source not show, you could test Kinect on other computer

Comment: I solved that problem. now how to save these bitmap images on hardisk?

Comment: [How to save kinect color video as stream on hard disk by Kinect SDK 2 in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010067/how-to-save-kinect-color-video-as-stream-on-hard-disk-by-kinect-sdk-2-in-wpf/31042326#31042326)         [How to save kinect color video as stream on hard disk by Kinect SDK 2 in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010067/how-to-save-kinect-color-video-as-stream-on-hard-disk-by-kinect-sdk-2-in-wpf)